# Why java form is too small when runtime

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm using Mac and install Parallels to run window then I installed netbeans to run java code, but when I run a form, the form is very small. I had no idea about this problem.here is the screenshot picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5nDE.png)

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

When you create the frame, add `frame.pack()` to set the size of the frame automatically based on the components.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("my frame");

/* Add all components */

frame.pack();
```

Comment: Happy 'triple digit rep.'. :)